# I would like to Custom Search(Advanced Search) an O365 Tenant to retrieve Title/Dept/JobTitle/Region

Tags: office-365

I have an O365 Tenant and all the information of users are stored in Azure AD, is there a way to query Azure AD and get the  Title/Dept/JobTitle/Region of the person.

This is for a retail industry where they have store associates who need to do a quick lookup for users Title/Dept/Job Title/Region, currently the company is using a third party and they would like to move out of it and find a solution within O365 using the Search functionality.

Please Advise. Thank You